# Action items not selectable Android Sherlock Actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm implementing action bar with items. I can't see the selected item effect (background selection color) when I click on an item in the actions :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_item_share_action_provider_action_bar"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="TTTTTTT"
        android:checkable="true"
         />


     <item android:id="@+id/menu_item_share_action_provider_action_bar"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="AAAAAA"
        android:checkable="true"

      />

</menu>
```

On My SherlockActivity :

```
  @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

              return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

You need to do something like this (switching the icons ids):

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // app icon in action bar clicked; go home
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

-----------
Have you done something like this:

```
@Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
 }
```

This is needed to inflate the XML file.

Comment: Yes sure. And I can see the menu items

Answer (score 0):

Maybe setting identical id's on both items is causing the problem. Did you try to change one of them?